# Django Admin MediaOrderConflictWarning

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-media, django-2.1

Ever since upgrading to Django 2.1, I am receiving a runtime error

```
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/svod-api-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py:126: 
MediaOrderConflictWarning: Detected duplicate Media files in an opposite order:
admin/js/collapse.js
admin/js/inlines.js
MediaOrderConflictWarning,
```

I think it is because have one collapsed fieldset in my model admin class and my tabular inline classes are to be collapsed as well.

If I remove either the fieldset collapse class or the inline collapse classes, the warning goes away, but it seems they cause a warning when they are both used at the same time.

The [Django 2.1-dev docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-2-docs-zh-cn/master/django-2-docs-zh-cn.pdf) say

> In older versions, forms and formsets combine their Media
>   with widget Media by concatenating the two. The combining now tries to preserve the relative order of elements in each list. MediaOrderConflictWarning is issued if the order can’t be preserved.

but I can't find a way to fix the media ordering while keeping all the original collapsed classes.  Has anyone else encountered the same problem?

```
    @admin.register(User)
    class UserModelAdmin(UserAdmin, ExportMixin):
        ...
        fieldsets = (
            (    
                _('Authentication'), {
                    'classes': (
                        'collapse',
                    ),
                    'fields': (
                        'username',
                        'password',
                        'user_permissions',
                        'groups'
                    )
                } 
            ),
            (
                _('Status'), {
                    'fields': (
                        'is_active',
                        'is_staff',
                        'is_superuser'
                    )
                }
            ),
            ... 
        )

        inlines = (
            DeviceTabularInline,
            PaymentTabularInline
        )


    class DeviceTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Device
        classes = ('collapse',)
        ...


    class PaymentTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Payment
        classes = ('collapse',) 
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, I just noticed a similar warning on an admin page with a date (and calendar widget) and inline classes that had a date (and calendar widget) -- `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py:126: MediaOrderConflictWarning: Detected duplicate Media files in an opposite order:  admin/js/calendar.js admin/js/inlines.js     MediaOrderConflictWarning,`

Comment: I am getting similar warning for `admin/js/calendar.js` and `admin/js/inlines.js`, did you figure out how to fix this yet?

Comment: Checking this ticket and comment would help solving this warning https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28866#comment:6

Comment: @AniketSinha, see Noortheen Raja's commet :)

Comment: Do you have some `Media` in your inlines?